# How does PHP actually work?

Tags: php, internals

Is there some guide out there that describes how the PHP internals?

- How files are loaded (required, included)?
- How they are parsed and executed?
- How memory is allocated?
- How objects are created/destroyed?
- How external modules are loaded?
- How the stack/heap works?
- How opcode caching actually work?
- Common hacks and performance tips?

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question and should not have been closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're you should look for resources on PHP Internal development. Looking for this information elsewhere will be really scattered.

I suggest picking up a PHP Core development book from your local book store and giving it a read. PHP.net has an [underdeveloped beginners reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) if you wanted to start there.

Comment: The link you suggested in really close to what I need and unless I get a better answer, you're getting my vote :)

Comment: Okay :D. As I said though, that reference is extremely underdeveloped; there are a lot of blank pages. Perhaps cross-referencing what you can with ZE1 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.php) might help, but I'm not sure how backwards compatible ZE2 is.

Answer (score 6):

This excellent although somewhat outdated [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) by Sara Golemon has answers to the most of your questions. Otherwise, the best way to learn php internals is to compile a debug version of it and run it step by step under a debugger. I did it once and it was an exciting experience.